# loading Mllib of Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to build a very simple scala standalone app using the Mllib, but I get the following error when trying to bulid the program:

```
Object Mllib is not a member of package org.apache.spark
```

Comment: Please show us your sbt file.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the package -

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib._
```

And follow the guide here. 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-guide.html